# Show menu bar (always) using python Qt4 (pyqt) in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqt

I am starting with pyQt4, aiming to make a simple application. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and I am using pyQt4 Designer, but also trying to make it from scratch. When I create a menu bar it doesn't appear unless I maximize the window. I have realized, looking to some other soft made with pyQt like QGIS, that this issue may be normal in Ubuntu.

The question: 
**is there any way to force the application to show the menu bar even if it is not maximized?**

I could put the code, but I think is irrelevant.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not a problem of Qt, it's a feature of Ubuntu's Unity shell called global menu bar. And since Ubuntu 14.04 it can be switched off: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/ubuntu-desktop-moving-application-menus-back-into-application-windows/

Comment: Thank you, It solves my problem partially, but I have seen some soft that keeps the menu bar even with the switch off. Is there a way to do it with pyQt?

Comment: It can be done, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem of Qt, it's a feature of Ubuntu's Unity shell called global menu bar. And since Ubuntu 14.04 [it can be switched off](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/ubuntu-desktop-moving-application-menus-back-into-application-windows/).

But if you want your menu to take its place on top of a window regardless of graphical shell preferences, you should use Qt menu bar instead of native one:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        toolMenu = QtGui.QMenuBar()
        toolMenu.setNativeMenuBar(False) # <--
        self.setMenuBar(toolMenu)

        for i in range(5):
            _ = toolMenu.addAction('Action {}'.format(i))
```

If you prefer, you can make this change in Qt Designer instead.  Select your `QMenuBar` object in the Object Inspector tree, scroll down in the Property Editor to the `QMenuBar` section, and uncheck the `nativeMenuBar` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
menuBar = self.menuBar()
mainMenu.setNativeMenuBar(False)
```